# Nuance of infinitive phrase `to stand watch` in the sentence

Tags: difference, register, reduced-relative-clauses

In the movie "The Hobbit", Erlond tells Gandalf:

> You are not the only guardian **to stand watch** over Middle-earth.

I'm not sure if there's any nuance with the use of the form `to stand watch`.
If I were to say such a sentence, I'd say:

> You are not the only guardian **that is standing watch** over Middle-earth.

Is there a difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is more ambiguous in meaning. It could mean:

> You are not the only guardian **who has ever stood watch** over Middle-earth.

or:

> You are not the only guardian **currently standing watch** over Middle-earth.

Your second version only has the second meaning.

Comment: Is the first form less often heard in spoken English compared to the other forms? I mean, would I sound like e.g. character from a book or more formal when using the first form compared to the other two forms?

Comment: @PawełB - Your assumption is accurate, I think. Many things are uttered in Middle Earth in ways that you probably wouldn't hear at a pub or in a bus station.